# Skype API (SKYPE4COMLib). How to read chat message that hasn't been sent yet?

Tags: skype, skype4com

Is it possible to read chat message **that hasn't been sent yet**? I want to show some tips for user when he/she is writing a message...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kinda suggestions? Because your question seems like you want to read minds of your users..

Comment: I want to read my minds, for example to check grammar or auto-complete feature.